# How to do performance tuning for huge MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have a MySQL table `MtgoxTrade(id,time,price,amount,type,tid)` with more than 500M+ records, i need to query the three fields (time,price,amount) from all records:

```
SELECT time, price, amount FROM MtgoxTrade;
```

It spends 110 seconds on Win7 which is too slow,my questions are:

1. Will a compound index help on this? Note that my SQL query has no `WHERE` clause
2. Any other optimization could be made improve the query performance here?

**Updated: I'm sorry that MtgoxTrade table have totally 6 fields: (id,time,price,amount,type,tid). My SQL only need to query three fields (time,price,amount). And i already tried to add composite index on (time,price,amount), but seems no help.**

Comment: try this, `ALTER TABLE MtgoxTrade INDEX (time, price, amount)`

Comment: show your table structure.

Comment: Retrieving 500 million rows in 110 seconds doesn't sound so bad. The real question is: why do you need to retrieve **all** rows from the table? I'm pretty sure no user will ever scroll through the complete result.

Comment: I have already added INDEX (time, price, amount), but it seems no help.

Comment: "*MtgoxTrade only have fields(id,time,price,amount)*" - So why does the table in your question suddenly have two more columns?

Comment: *2. Any other optimization could be made improve the query performance here?* In general, not using MySQL will help a lot.

Comment: I'm sorry that MtgoxTrade have fields(id,time,price,amount,type,tid). It is used to store financial data, i need query the table and convert to JSON format so it could be drawn as OHLC chart on browser.

Comment: @SimonWang: converting 500M+ rows table to JSON format does not sound like good idea at all. Maybe you can have your OHLC chart browser to read MySQL directly?

Comment: @mvp, the table stores raw trading data, it need to convert by some algorithm to generate OHLC JSON data, i think it could not be done on browser directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is your real query - NO, nothing could possibly help. Come to think of it - you are asking to deliver contents of whole 500M+ table! It will be slow no matter what you do - whole table must be processed.

If you can constrain your program logic to only process some smaller subset of your table, then it is possible to make it faster.

For example, you can process only results for last month using `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT time, price, amount
FROM MtgoxTrade
WHERE time BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND '2013-09-21'
```

This *can* work really fast, but you would still need to add index on `time` field, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX mtgoxtrade_time_idx ON mtgoxtrade (time);
```

Comment: @usr: if there is a primary key defined it will be a clustered index that contains all the rows anyway. And that index only differs by the `id` column from a compound index containing all three selected columns. So I doubt an index over the three selected columns will make much of a difference (although you are right, that it *could*)

Comment: I assumed that there are other columns which he is not selecting but I notice now that there aren't any. In that case your answer is correct. +1

Comment: This table have 6 fields total, i just query three fields. I do not care the fields order.

Comment: @usr: and now suddenly the table does have more columns.... In that case the index *might* help to reduce the total data volume to be read.

Comment: Besides the 3-column index (which can help), the next thing to check would be your hardware. Having more RAM and faster disks (like SSD) can help.

Comment: @ypercube: even SSD might be useless if he is connecting over network. Gigabit network maxes out at about 100MB/s, and typical modern HDD can deliver 130+MB/s. In other words, network will be bottleneck, not disk. If connection is local, then SSD may help.

Comment: I already add 3-column index, but it seems no help, still  need 110 seconds to run my SQL.

Comment: @SimonWang: you will **have to** find a way to process your data in smaller chunks. Processing whole table is dead end.